# Swift JSONEncoder.dataCodingStrategy custom function not being called

Tags: swift, jsonencoder

I have been trying to get `JSONEncoder`'s `dataEncodingStrategy` work.

I need to get my http body data **without escaped** on API requests and there is this `withoutEscapingSlashes: JSONEncoder.OutputFormatting` of `JSONEncoder` but unfortunately this is only for iOS >= 13 whereas my app supports iOS >= 11.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
   encoder.outputFormatting = .withoutEscapingSlashes
} else {
   // Fallback to earlier versions here!
   // Looking for a workaround and I believe "dataEncodingStrategy" is what I am looking for.
}
try encoder.encode(data)
```

Here is a simple example from Playground for test purpose to show you what I wrote.

`JSONEncoder.DataEncodingStrategy.custom` (that is *var strategy*) is never called.

```
import Foundation

struct Model: Encodable {
    let key: String = "key goes here..."
}

var strategy: JSONEncoder.DataEncodingStrategy = .custom({ (data, encoder) in
    print("CALLED!") // This is never printed.
    if var string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        string = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "key", with: "REPLACED")
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        let data = string.data(using: .utf8)
        try container.encode(data)
    }
})

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.dataEncodingStrategy = strategy

let m = Model()
let d = try! encoder.encode(m)
let str = String(data: d, encoding: .utf8)
print(str)
```

`dataEncodingStrategy` is always dismissed no matter what. It is **never** called. It is not deprecated or something. Does anybody know what is going on here?

*Although this question is specific to `JSONEncoder`'s `dataEncodingStrategy`, any other approach for keeping http body data without escaped for iOS < 13 would be helpful as well.*

Comment: `dataEncodingStrategy` – as the name implies – is how to encode values declared as `Data` . It has nothing to do with output formatting.

Answer (score 1):

`dataEncodingStrategy` is specifically for encoding values of type `Data`, not types like `String` that are natively supported.

Unfortunately, your only option to my knowledge for iOS < 13 is to basically do what you were trying to do in your encoding strategy closure — use `.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\/", with: "/")` on the encoded JSON string.